# Use python, to open cmd window with the directory supplied as an argument as the current directory

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file, cmd, subprocess

I want to use Python to open a directory in a Win10 cmd window, and keep the window open.

I made a batch file named: `open_dir_in_cmd_window.CMD`:

```
CD /D %1
```

I tested that batch file successfully, by creating another batch file named, `Test.cmd`:

```
Rem "open_dir_in_cmd_window.CMD" "f:\backup"
"open_dir_in_cmd_window.CMD" "f:\backup"
```

A [very helpful webpage](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) provides the following example, which I seem unable to follow correctly:

> Spaces in Program Path + parameters with spaces:
>
> ```
> CMD /k ""c:\batch files\demo.cmd" "Parameter 1 with space" "Parameter2 with space""
> ```

I made a python script, which contains the following lines, which alas, triggers an error message:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(cmd /k "E:\open_dir_in_cmd_window.CMD f:\backup")
```

When I open a Command Prompt window and run:

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" E:\open_dir.py
```

I get an error message, `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, with this:

> ```
> subprocess.run(cmd /k "E:\open_dir_in_cmd_window.CMD f:\backup")
>                                                               ^
> ```

I've tried many different permutations of double quoting and can't figure out the right way to do it.

I have spent many hours hunting on the web and trying to figure this out and I do not know what to do.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is the error in python? shouldn't that be `subprocess.run(r'cmd /k "E:\open_dir_in_cmd_window.CMD f:\backup"')`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, which I implemented.  Now, I do get a Cmd prompt window, but "open_dir_in_cmd_window.CMD" (aka "the batch file") is not working properly because the directory shown is the dir where the python script is located, instead of "f:\backup".  I am trying to learn how to capture the stdout and stderr, in the hope that capturing that info will help me find out why the batch file is not working properly. Do you know some code I could use to trap the stdout and stderr?

Comment: Your code appears to do the trick.  Thank you so much.  How can I give you credit for answering my question?

Comment: i think you are confusing the syntaxes between batch, a string-based language VS python?

Comment: you can upvote my other posts :D Just kidding. btw, why is there need for two programming languages, why not just batch or python?